# Android AsyncTask + Handler, no data updated to Main Activity UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

We have an main activity with a Text View which is requested to auto-retrieve data from TCP server in LAN.
We enabled AsyncTask in updateData() to call Connect to call Handler to update TextView named mTvVoc, and refresh connection by beginConnect().

The problem is the mTvVoc is not updated, it seems the AsyncTask does not function as expected?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updateData();
}


    public void updateData(final String order) {
        Connect(HOST, PORT, order);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                System.out.println("get data from order--->" + order);
                beginConnect(HOST, PORT, order);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);                
            }

        }.execute();
    }

    public String Connect(final String HOST, final int PORT, final String OderType) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
                    bufferedInputStream = new     BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    System.out.println("bufferedInputStream--->" + bufferedInputStream);
                    printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        if (!socket.isOutputShutdown()) {
                            printWriter.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer
                                 .parseInt(OderType)));
                        }
                    }

                    while (true) {
                        if (!socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected() && !socket.isInputShutdown()) {
                            int temp = 0;
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            while ((temp = bufferedInputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                                isConn(socket);
                                Log.d("Data received", new String(buf, 0, temp));
                                acceptinfo = new String(buf, 0, temp);
                                System.out.println("Data received====》" + acceptinfo);
                                Message message = new Message();
                                message.what = 1;
                                message.obj = acceptinfo;
                                handler.sendMessage(message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    System.out.println("UnknownHostException-->connection failed");
                    stopConnect();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException-->connection failed");
                    stopConnect();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return acceptinfo;
    }


    public String beginConnect(final String HOST, final int PORT, final String OderType) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
                    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    System.out.println("bufferedInputStream--->" + bufferedInputStream);
                    printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                    if (socket.isConnected()) {
                        if (!socket.isOutputShutdown()) {
                                 printWriter.println(Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(OderType)));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    System.out.println("UnknownHostException-->connection failed");
                    stopConnect();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException-->connection failed");
                    stopConnect();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return acceptinfo;
    }


    public Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.i("message", msg.obj.toString());
            if (msg.what == 0) {
                mIvContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.wangluo_gray);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                reGetData();
            }
            if (msg.what == 1) {
                String info = msg.obj.toString();
                if (info.length() != 18) {
                    mIvContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.wangluo_gray);
                    System.out.println("data verification failed");
                    reGetData();
                    return;
                }

                String iszeroupString = info.substring(1, 3);
                String temperature = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(info.substring(3, 5), 16));
                String vocValue = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(info.substring(7, 9), 16));
                mTvVoc.setText(getVOC((Integer.valueOf(vocValue ) / 100.00)));

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Pretty strange you have a Connect() and a beginConnect,() which both connect to a server. So two client instances. Why would you do so? Makes no sense.

Comment: And you start new Threads in doInBackground wich is completely wrong. Just put your code in doInBackground directly without wrapping it in a thread. And do not twice connect. Well unless you have a very good reason to do so but which you did not tell us. Use a thread or an async task. Not both.

Comment: so I need to remove beginConnect()?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot directly communicate from background thread to UI thread to
>   update any UI components.

Use this in your background thread to update `textview` from `AsyncTask.`

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
        // update your text here 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update on UI, you need to run the codes in `UIThread`. See code below and put in your handler:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("message", msg.obj.toString());
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            mIvContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.wangluo_gray);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            reGetData();
        }
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            String info = msg.obj.toString();
            if (info.length() != 18) {
                mIvContent.setImageResource(R.drawable.wangluo_gray);
                System.out.println("data verification failed");
                reGetData();
                return;
            }

            String iszeroupString = info.substring(1, 3);
            String temperature = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(info.substring(3, 5), 16));
            String vocValue = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(info.substring(7, 9), 16));
            mTvVoc.setText(getVOC((Integer.valueOf(vocValue ) / 100.00)));

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty bad to code that handler to update the gui. Do away with it as AsyncTask provides already the functionality to do so.

You should have looked better at the many examples.

Use `publishProgress()` and `onProgressUpdate()` to update a progress bar and/or other gui elements.

And do not wrap your code in a thread if it has to be executed in `doInBackground()`.